# ANCOVA: How does a covariate give insight when comparing the mean to the adjusted mean?

Tags: ancova

When comparing the direction and magnitude of the difference between the original means and the adjusted means what does the change say about the covariate?

For example: IV = Grade, DV = Test Score, Covariate = IQ Score

Am I correct in assuming that if a group's **adjusted mean** is higher than its original mean that the effect of the covariate (higher IQ) is that it decreases the DV (Test Score) thus resulting in the higher adjusted mean?

Comment: Welcome to the site.I attempted to clarify your first paragraph. If I messed up, please correct it.

As to your question, why not just look at the parameter estimate for the covariate? That seems much more straightforward

Comment: I see the parameter estimate read out in SPSS but am unclear how to interpret it.

Comment: The parameter readout for the covariate is the predicted relationship between a 1 point gain on IQ (the covariate) on score (the DV).  At least, unless you have coded something strangely.

Comment: I seem to have figured it out, the direction and magnitude of the adjustment on the DV mirrors the adjustment of the covariate, is this correct reasoning?

Comment: I think so, but you are using odd language.